# Using Ajax to change the value of 2 PHP variables in real time (received from external file)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form class="addtowatchlistform" action="logo/insertwatchlist.php" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'"/>
    <button id="addtowatchlistbutton" type="submit" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'" data-tooltip="'.$addremove.' TO YOUR WATCHLIST" class="material-icons" style="color:'.$watchlisticoncolor.'">add_box</button>

</form>

   // Same form as above
<form class="addtowatchlistform" action="logo/insertwatchlist.php" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'"/>
    <button id="addtowatchlistbutton" type="submit" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'" data-tooltip="'.$addremove.' TO YOUR WATCHLIST" class="material-icons" style="color:'.$watchlisticoncolor.'">add_box</button>

</form>
```

Jquery Code:

```
<script>
$(".addtowatchlistform").submit(function(e) {
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  var url = $(this).attr("action");
  $.post(url, data, function() {

  });
  return false;
});
</script>
```

What it currently do?

When someone click on `add_box` (submits the form) button, it runs `insert.php` in the background.

The `insert.php` file sets 2 variables inside it, i.e:

`$addremove` and `$watchlisticoncolor`. I want to run this variables in my main file also. (You can find those variables inside `<form>` tag, I want to replace them), in the real time without reloading the page.

How can I do it with Jquery or PHP ajax code?

Comment: So you want to update the page with values from the server?  Your `insertwatchlist.php` would have to return the data you want back to the client (likely by echoing JSON data) and the client-side code would use that data to update the page (in the currently empty AJAX callback function).

Comment: Yes @David sir.

Comment: Ok, so where are you stuck?  There are *many* examples of using AJAX with PHP.  What is the data you're trying to return to the client?  How are you returning that data?  How are you trying to use it on the client?

Comment: I just don't know how to do it. I tried a lot of things, but i am still learning Jquery. I did not added them to the question, because it will not add anything to the question and make it more confusing, in my opinion.

Comment: You should definitely start by making some effort.  Focus on a specific part of what you're trying to build.  For example, returning the data from the server.  The client-side callback function can just `console.log` that data for now so you can check if it's being returned.  What is the data you're trying to return from the server and how are you trying to return it?  Your attempt certainly *is* relevant to the question because we are here to help you with that.  Stack Overflow does not seek to replace tutorials and is not a personal tutoring service.

Comment: Ok sir, I will add few more things that I tried. By the way, since it is PHP variable that `insertwatchllist.php` is returning, should I use PHP ajax to do this action or Jquery?

Comment: You would use PHP for your server-side code and JavaScript for your client-side code.  The fact that it's AJAX doesn't change the fundamental nature of how web applications work.  Server-side code runs on the server, client-side code runs on the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggested you can use JSON data to exchange the data you want between the server and the client

**the server code (insertwatchlist.php) file**

```
<?php
$response = new \stdClass();
$response->addremove = "item1";//you can get the data anyway you want(e.g database)
$response->watchlisticoncolor = "red";
die(json_encode($response));
```

And your **client side ajax function** could be something like this

```
$.post(url, data, function() {
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $("button#addtowatchlistbutton").data('tooltip', data.addremove + " TO YOUR WATCHLIST");
        $("button#addtowatchlistbutton").css('color',data.watchlisticoncolor);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("json encoding failed");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Sir, it do not update the value of variables. I cannot tell you why, because it shows no error.

Comment: Did you get any result from the server? What does `console.log(data);` at the first line of the AJAX function log ?

Comment: No result from the server sir

Comment: Then you need to know why your PHP script did not executed?

Comment: Oh, do you mean this? This is what insertwatchlist.php echo `{"addremove":"item1","watchlisticoncolor":"red"}`

Comment: @Toby This is the result from the server, so far so good.Now the JavaScript code changes the color of the buttons and the tool-tip data according to the values came from the server

Comment: The JQuery code selects the `<button>` element that has the id `addtowatchlistbutton` then changes it's color and the tootip data.

Comment: I found the bug. It should be `$.post(url, data, function(data) {` , after adding `data, it works perfectly, thanks

Comment: @Toby Great. I'm sorry i didn't notice that, I was focused on the jQuery selectors and the DOM, congratulations you did it man